# Correct syntax for signal handlers?

Tags: python, signals, pygtk, signal-handling

I've searched among the documentation of Python, and PyGtk but i couldn't find the right syntax for a generic signal handler written by the programmer; i've just found the documentation for the classic API provided by the library(PyGtk).

This is the syntax for my function for every method i've in my modules:

```
def Continua_Button_clicked(self, widget, event, *args):
```

But is it correct?

How can i be sure i'll got the widget reference, the event that fired up the signal handler and the arguments of the event?

I'm a bit confused of what and how many arguments i'll got from each event, and how many arguments my signal handler will get.

Comment: gtk.Widget Signal Prototypes!! yeah this one, write an official reply so i can give you "the green tick", thanksss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the signal what exactly is passed in; you'd consult the [`gkt.Widget` signal documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkwidget.html#id4109782).

For example, the `button-press-event` signal expects:

```
def callback(widget, event, *user_params):
```

but `child-notify` will use:

```
def callback(widget, child_property, *user_params)
```

etc.